# How do I make Chrome the default browser in the OSX Guest Account?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, guest-account

I'd like to make Chrome the default browser in the OSX. I've managed to get Chrome added to the guest account but there are several issues

1. Everytime the guest account is launched **after reboot** Chrome needs root permission to check for updates. How do I turn this off or set up the guest account so that Chrome doesn't ask (as in it thinks it has already asked)

   [image]
2. Every time the guess account is launched the user is ask if they want to make Chrome the default. How can I get this not to happen?

   [image]
3. When Chrome finally starts it asks the user to login. I'd like it to start just on the Google home page. How can I do that?

   [image]

I'm guessing all 3 of these might be related to some how running Chrome once in guest mode and copying some configuration files out of guest mode into the correct place so that next time guest mode is run those files already exist and chrome thinks it's already been set up.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial point to realize with the Guest account is that the User homefolder it creates, with preferences set in its /Library/Preferences folder, are wiped upon logout.

To effect changes, you need to make the changes (add the specific preference files) in the /System/Library/User Template/English.lproj folder. This folder contains the generic template User Homefolder structure used when creating a new user or the Guest User.

[This page](http://gigaom.com/2010/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-user-template-in-snow-leopard/) has details about how it is done in Snow Leopard, but it is applicable to Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you may need to unhide the hiden files so open terminal and run those commands :

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder
```

To switch back, do the same but substitute FALSE for TRUE.

Now 
Login to your guest account, there set chrome as your default browser (or even Firefox) 
Then do not logout ! This would erase your session, so use the  on the top right corner use the swich user drop down menue, 
Now that you are back again in your Admin account,
Find the new temporary guest home folder, under

```
 Users/Guest
```

Select all the folders inside of it,
And copy them in :

```
 /System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/
```

English or whatever your languish is if you are using your computer in french this should be :

```
  /System/Library/User Template/French.lproj/
```

as you can see in this folder there was the defaults folders for the guest account 
By modifying them you have just modified default appearance of the guest user account
You may want to save this folder in a safe place before, in case you want to undo your work.

For reference , 
You just have to follow the steps as shown in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU-W2-_c5bA

Or if you prefer text version :

http://www.michaelsmac.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=394

Comment: Ok make sense, I will try, but it's long and takes time ...

Comment: So, that's all I can do I have to leave now !

Comment: You should use pkill instead of killall

Comment: @GoodPerson Realy, why ?

Comment: more portable; killall on some systems means "kill all the processes running"

Comment: Interesting ! I am on Linux now, no possibility to try it out so I let it like that for now. Anyone who want to do an edit is welcome.

Comment: https://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/admin-mistakes-solaris-killall/